# GUI tool for php web development

Tags: php, web-deployment

Like visual studio where we have two section source and design for web programming,
is there any tool in linux where we can perform php web development which gives GUI+Source section for designing?

Something like drag and drop adjustment for GUI part.

Answer (score 0):

[PDT for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) maybe an option for you. Eclipse runs on PC, Linux, and Mac. [Aptana studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) has built in support for php and is also available for linux, last but not least [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=php) has php dev tools also, [Jetbrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/index.html) (its not free), but Aptana is also based on Eclipse but is specifically geared towards web development and has built in support for debugging and as well as built in support for git if that matters to you. I personally don't use netbeans.